# Logic Pro X Score creates triplets instead of a measure packed with 16th notes

Tags: logic-pro

I have some midi in 3/4 time, and I'm trying to encode 12 16th notes in a row. It looks right in the piano roll, and sounds right on playback:

[image: Piano Roll view]

But then I look at the guitar tab score, and it turns it into three triplets with overlapping notes. Which is not at all correct. I haven't selected the triplet annotation from the parts box or anything.

[image: Guitar tab view]

Also in Piano staff:

[image: Piano score view]

Any idea what's going on with the display here, and how do I get the score to display as 12 individual notes with the correct timing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try opening your score editor then on the left hand side make sure the “region” box is opened. The second item down in the region box is “quantize”. This is the quantizing of the visual written notes, not the actual recorded rhythms.

“Quantize” is a flip menu. Yours might be set to 4,12 or 8,12. Change it to 16,12 or 16 and that should do the trick.

Below are 2 examples from my program of the score and piano roll with quantize set to different values circled:

[image]

[image]